# laravel Eloquent ORM delete() method

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Hi I am studying laravel.
I use Eloquent ORM delete method but I get a different result.Not true or false but null.
I set an resource route and there is a destroy method in UsersController.

```
public function destroy($id){

  $res=User::find($id)->delete();
  if ($res){
    $data=[
    'status'=>'1',
    'msg'=>'success'
  ];
  }else{
    $data=[
    'status'=>'0',
    'msg'=>'fail'
  ];
  return response()->json($data);
```

But I always get a response {"status":"0","msg":"failed"},the record in the database is deleted.

Then I use dd($res) .It shows null in the page.

But from the course I learn it returns a boolean value true or false.

Is there any error in my code?

Can you tell me some other method that I can get a boolean result when I delete data from database?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Before `delete` , there are several methods in laravel.

`User::find(1)` and `User::first()` return an instance.

`User::where('id',1)->get` and `User::all()` return a collection of instance.

call `delete` on an model instance returns `true/false`

```
$user=User::find(1);
$user->delete(); //returns true/false
```

call `delete` on a collection of instance returns a number which represents the number of the records deleted

```
//assume you have 10 users, id from 1 to 10;
$result=User::where('id','<',11)->delete(); //returns 11 (the number of the records deleted)

//lets call delete again
$result2=User::where('id','<',11)->delete(); //returns 0 (we have already delete the id<11 users, so this time we delete nothing, the result should be the number of the records deleted(0)  )
```

Also there are other delete methods, you can call `destroy` as a model static method like below

```
$result=User::destroy(1,2,3);
$result=User::destroy([1,2,3]);
$result=User::destroy(collect([1, 2, 3]));
//these 3 statement do the same thing, delete id =1,2,3 users, returns the number of the records deleted
```

One more thing ,if you are new to `laravel` ,you can use `php artisan tinker` to see the result, which is more efficient and then `dd($result)` , `print_r($result);`

Answer (score 139):

I think you can change your query and try it like :

```
$res=User::where('id',$id)->delete();
```

Comment: What will be in $res variable? Will it return boolean - true for deleted, false for not deleted Or delete record id? Kindly confirm. Thanks.

Comment: what if I have the model itself?  like $file object ?

Comment: Behind the scenes will `$res=User::where('id',$id)->delete();` be 2 queries or 1?

Comment: Also read: https://devnote.in/how-to-delete-record-by-id-using-laravel-eloquent/

Answer (score 19):

At first,

You should know that `destroy()` is correct method for removing an entity directly via object or model and `delete()` can only be called in query builder.

In your case, You have not checked if record exists in database or not. Record can only be deleted if exists.

So, You can do it like follows.

```
$user = User::find($id);
    if($user){
        $destroy = User::destroy(2);
    }
```

The value or `$destroy` above will be 0 or 1 on fail or success respectively. So, you can alter the `$data` array like:

```
if ($destroy){

    $data=[
        'status'=>'1',
        'msg'=>'success'
    ];

}else{

    $data=[
        'status'=>'0',
        'msg'=>'fail'
    ];

}
```

Hope, you understand.

Comment: thanks for the note.I use the query builder (where) and it works.Then I try User::destroy($id) it returns 0.But the record in the table disappear .I have a foreign key on id,Is that the reason that I get a zero result while the deletion works?

Answer (score 5):

**Laravel** Eloquent provides `destroy()` function in which returns `boolean` value. So if a record **exists** on the database and **deleted** you'll get `true` otherwise `false`.

Here's an example using **Laravel Tinker shell**.

[image: delete operation result]

In this case, your code should look like this:

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        $res = User::destroy($id);
        if ($res) {
            return response()->json([
                'status' => 1,
                'msg' => 'success'
            ]);
        } else {
            return response()->json([
                'status' => 0,
                'msg' => 'fail'
            ]);
        }
    }
```

More info about [Laravel Eloquent Deleting Models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#deleting-models)

Answer (score 4):

```
$model=User::where('id',$id)->delete();
```

Answer (score 2):

check before delete the user  otherwise throws error exeption

```
$user=User::find($request->id);
  
   if($user)
   {
   // return $user;           <------------------------user exist
       if($user->delete()){
         return 'user deleted';
         }
    else{
       return "something wrong";
        }   

   }
  else{
     return "user not exist";// <--------------------user not exist
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can delete the data using two ways.
First, using **find**
Second, using **where** with model
You can try something like this.
First:

```
User::find($id)->destroy();
```

Or Second Way

```
User::where('id', $id)->delete();
```

Now Please try it will return you True/False result.