# Laravel - Collection::delete method does not exist

Tags: laravel

I am trying to test the boot() static::deleting method, which should fire when a model is deleted through Eloquent.

The command in tinker `App\User::find(6)->delete();` returns a 'method [...]Collection::delete does not exist'.

If I try to use `App\User::where('id', 6)->delete();` then the static::deleting method does not get triggered since Eloquent is not loaded. If I load Eloquent with `->first()` then I get the same error that states method does not exist.

Here is the entire user model

```
 <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    public function profile() {
        return $this->hasOne(Profile::class);
    }

    public function posts() {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
    }

    public function tempUploads() {
        return $this->hasMany(TempUploads::class);
    }
    
    protected static function boot() {
        parent::boot();
        
        static::created(function ($user) {
            $user->profile()->create(['id' => $user->username, 'avatar' => '/storage/avatars/edit-profile.png']);
            mkdir(public_path() . "/storage/images/" . $user->username , 0755);

            // $data = [
            //  'user_id' => $user->username
            // ];
            // Mail::to($user->email)->send(new WelcomeMail($data));
        });

        static::deleting(function ($user) {
            $user->posts->delete();
            if ($user->profile->avatar != '/storage/avatars/edit-profile.png') {
                if ($user->profile->cover != NULL && $user->profile->cover != '') {
                    $oldAvatar = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $user->profile->avatar;
                    $oldCover = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $user->profile->cover;
                    if (is_file($oldAvatar) && is_file($oldCover)) {
                        unlink($oldAvatar);
                        unlink($oldCover);
                    } else {
                        die("Грешка при изтриване на стария файл. File does not exist in profile deleting method.");
                    }
                }
            }
            $user->profile->delete();
        });
    }

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'username', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

I have spent hours now looking through google for possible solutions but nothing has yet.

How should I properly delete a User model while triggering the boot deleting method ?

Comment: if you have defined the listener already can you paste that code

Comment: im sorry im not quite sure i understand what your advise is, can you rephrase it ?

Comment: `find` should only be returning a Collection if you are passing it an array .. otherwise you should get a single model instance or null and should be able to call `delete` on the model instance

Comment: `delete()` can only be called on `QueryBuilder` instance [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45458074/laravel-eloquent-orm-delete-method)

Comment: @user3647971 what method should I use then to remove the model in order to trigger the deleting method as well ?

Comment: @DenislavKaragiozov `destroy()` method is the correct one there. See the link.

Comment: @user3647971 no the Model has a `delete` method   https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#deleting-models

Comment: @lagbox delete method doesn't work with Collections(many querybuilder results). Destroy method loops through the collection calling delete on each of them individually.

Comment: @user3647971 App\User::destroy(6) returns the same error

Comment: @DenislavKaragiozov How about App\User::where('id',6)->get()->destroy(); ?

Comment: same error, destroy does not exist

Comment: @DenislavKaragiozov And delete instead of destroy in that one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your `deleting` listener you are trying to delete something else, which is a Collection which is causing the error.

`$user->posts` is a relationship to Posts which is a plural which is a hasMany relationship (most likely) so it returns a Collection **always**. Collections do not have a `delete` method. You will have to iterate through the collection and call `delete` on each Post

```
// calling `delete()` on a Collection not a Model
// will throw the error you see
$user->posts->delete();

// iterate through the Collection
foreach ($user->posts as $post) {
    $post->delete();
}
```

Side Note: you can not do any action in bulk with Models and queries and have the events be fired. All Model events are based on single instances of the Models. A direct query bypasses the Model.

Comment: i think that did it, i had to exit tinker and load it up again in order for the changes to be applied ! Thanks bud !

Answer (score 6):

You can optimise [lagbox's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62696105/8394877) by using only one query to delete all of the posts. In his example he's executing a `delete` query for every post attached to the user.

For a single `delete` query either use the query builder of the relationship directly:

```
$user->posts()->delete();
```

or use the [`pluck` method](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-pluck) of the collection and a separate query:

```
Post::where('id', $user->posts->pluck('id'))->delete();
```

Comment: only issue is if they want to listen for events for the Post model as they will not fire for either of these queries as they are direct

Comment: Thanks bud, it was a matter of adding () and boom problem solved ! I understand where I did wrong, that's what is important so thank you !

Comment: Does this question fall into category of typo? Since the code worked with fixed syntax?

Comment: i was using the property 'posts', instead of calling the method 'posts()' so, I guess it does. Is it true though that this will not trigger the event listener for posts though?
`$user->posts()->delete();`

Comment: It should trigger it when using the first example

Comment: Not sure so one thing to look into.

Comment: this DOES NOT trigger the deleting method, so I have selected lagbox's answer, thank you for your contribution though

Comment: Inspired in this code, I attempted to destroy a record [but it's destroying at what looks like random](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66443193/5675325)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [higher order messages](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#higher-order-messages) as well:

```
$user->posts->each->delete();
```

Answer (score 1):

`$user->posts->map->delete()`

Comment: New answers to old, well-answered questions require ample explanation as to how this complements the other answers.

Comment: its required only one line code.
we can use the benefit of the observer we define during the delete model.
it also takes benefit of the eloquent model provided during deleting a single model.

Comment: So explain that in your answer please. Does it improve all other answers?

Answer (score 1):

```
$user->posts()->delete()   will work

$user->posts->delete()   will not work
```

**Because** if you not put **'()'** then it becomes collection instead of query. delete() works on query

Answer (score 0):

I used this in my Controller File to delete the Database Entry:

```php
public function destroy(Item $id) {
        $id->destroy($id->id);
        //return view('inv.delete', compact('id'));
        return redirect('/inv');
    }
```