# Laravel destroy nested resource

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I have a resource name **OrganizationEmailDomain**

```
Route::resource('organizations.emaildomains', 'OrganizationEmailDomainController', ['except' => ['show']]);
```

and able to index it just fine

[image]

In that view, when clicking in the three dots there's the destroy part

```
<form action="{{ route('organizations.emaildomains.destroy', ['organization' => $id, 'emaildomain' => $email_domain->id]) }}" method="post">
    @csrf
    @method('delete')
    <button type="button" class="dropdown-item" onclick="confirm('{{ __("Are you sure you want to delete this email domain?") }}') ? this.parentElement.submit() : ''">
        {{ __('Delete') }}
    </button>
</form>
```

If in that index view I echo $email_domains (`<?php echo $email_domains;?>`) then I get as expected (note that the following was before the images were added, so the records don't match the images)

```
[{"id":1,"email_domain":"test.com","organization_id":1,"created_at":"2021-03-02T14:46:50.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-03-02T14:46:56.000000Z"},{"id":2,"email_domain":"gmail.com","organization_id":1,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null}]
```

When I try to destroy

```
/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  \App\OrganizationEmailDomain  $emailDomain
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy(Organization $organization, OrganizationEmailDomain $emailDomain)
{
    //dd($emailDomain);

    $emailDomain->delete();

    return redirect()->route('organizations.emaildomains.index',$organization->id)->withStatus(__("Organization's email domain successfully deleted."));
}
```

that `dd($emailDomain)` returns this

[image: dd($emailDomain);]

As [langbox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62696105/5675325) states

> (...) hasMany relationship (...) so it returns a Collection **always**

So, inspired in [this answer from Dan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62696231/5675325), just substituted

```
$emailDomain->delete();
```

with the following

```
$org_email = OrganizationEmailDomain::where('id', $organization->org_email_domains->pluck('id'))->delete();
```

given that in Organization model I have

```
/**
 * Get the email domains of the organization
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function org_email_domains()
{
    return $this->hasMany(OrganizationEmailDomain::class);
}
```

> What's the problem here?

It always deletes the record that is in the row above.

For example, let's delete `DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD`

[image]

this deleted the first row, `AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA`

[image]

If I then try to delete `BBBBBBBBBBBBBBB` (which now became the first row) it'll delete just fine.

---

For reference, here's the index.blade.php where the form I shared previously is at

```
<table class="table table-flush"  id="datatable-basic">
    <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">{{ __('Organization') }}</th>
            <th scope="col">{{ __('Email Domain') }}</th>
            <th scope="col">{{ __('Creation date') }}</th>
            @can('manage-org-emaildomains', App\User::class)
                <th scope="col"></th>
            @endcan
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach ($email_domains as $email_domain)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $organization->name }}</td>
                <td>{{ $email_domain->email_domain }}</td>
                <td>{{ $email_domain->created_at ? $email_domain->created_at->format('d/m/Y H:i') : "NULL" }}</td>
                @can('manage-org-emaildomains', App\User::class)
                    <td class="text-right">
                        @if (auth()->user()->can('update', $email_domain) || auth()->user()->can('show', $email_domain) || auth()->user()->can('delete', $email_domain))
                            <div class="dropdown">
                                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-icon-only text-light" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                    <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                                </a>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right dropdown-menu-arrow">
                                    @can('show', $email_domain)
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('organizations.emaildomains.show', ['organization' => $id, 'emaildomain' => $email_domain->id]) }}">{{ __('Show') }}</a>
                                    @endcan
                                    @can('update', $email_domain)
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('organizations.emaildomains.edit', ['organization' => $id, 'emaildomain' => $email_domain->id]) }}">{{ __('Edit') }}</a>
                                    @endcan
                                    @if (auth()->user()->can('delete', $email_domain))
                                        <form action="{{ route('organizations.emaildomains.destroy', ['organization' => $id, 'emaildomain' => $email_domain->id]) }}" method="post">
                                            @csrf
                                            @method('delete')
                                            <button type="button" class="dropdown-item" onclick="confirm('{{ __("Are you sure you want to delete this email domain?") }}') ? this.parentElement.submit() : ''">
                                                {{ __('Delete') }}
                                            </button>
                                        </form>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        @endif
                    </td>
                @endcan
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed the route to [shallow nesting](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#shallow-nesting)

```
Route::resource('organizations.emaildomains', 'OrganizationEmailDomainController', ['except' => ['show']])->shallow();
```

then the form to

```
<form action="{{ route('emaildomains.destroy', ['organization' => $id, 'emaildomain' => $email_domain->id]) }}" method="post">
    @csrf
    @method('delete')
    <button type="button" class="dropdown-item" onclick="confirm('{{ __("Are you sure you want to delete this email domain?") }}') ? this.parentElement.submit() : ''">
        {{ __('Delete') }}
    </button>
</form>
```

and the destroy() to

```
/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  \App\OrganizationEmailDomain  $emailDomain
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy(Request $request, OrganizationEmailDomain $emailDomain)
{
    $path = $request->path();

    $id = substr($path, strrpos($path, '/') + 1);

    $emailDomain = OrganizationEmailDomain::find($id);

    $emailDomain->delete();

    return redirect()->route('organizations.emaildomains.index',$request->query()['organization'])->withStatus(__("Organization's email domain successfully deleted."));
}
```

and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You cant delete just the id, you are passing only the id.

in the controller you Must do Find , Ex :

```
$flight = Flight::find($emaidomain);
```

then u do

```
$flight->delete();
```

You are just passing id in the form, you must find the item in the controller via the id then delete, u cant delete id only.

Comment: That will get a `Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::delete does not exist.`

Comment: Make sure that u add the Model class, and replace the (Fight) from the example with the model class name.