# Can I use first() with delete() in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I mean is there anything like this?

```
User::where(['id' => $id, 'role' => 'Teacher'])->first()->delete();
```

Though I used this

```
User::where(['id' => $id, 'role' => 'Teacher'])->delete();
```

So just want an idea about it

Comment: In this particular case, they'll do essentially the same thing, unless there are multiple users with that ID. (That'd be unusual; id is typically unique.) Do note that the `first()` approach will fire Eloquent observers; the second will not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [laravel Eloquent ORM delete() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45458074/laravel-eloquent-orm-delete-method)